# Alternative price rating approach

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, frontend

I'm pretty new to web development and I don't know if my solution it is O.K according to the best practices, considering performance and clean code.

I have a Merchant model that belongs to a Price model.

Price table:

```
create_table "prices", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "price_range"
  t.integer  "percentile"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

The current values inside the table:

> ```
> **price_range**    **percentile **
> Up to $20.00            20
> $20.01 to $40.00        40
> $40.01 to $60.00        60
> $60.01 to $80.00        80
> More than $80.00       100
> ```

To show this at my view I'm using:

```html
<div class="price-ratings">
  <div class="empty-prices"></div>
  <div class="full-prices" style= width:"<%= "#{@merchant.price.percentile}%" %></div>
</div>
```

According to the width value the dollar signals will be colored.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pknoll/dxdf8whv/)

I'm not sure about that approach. Anyone recommends a finest solution to achieve the same or that is OK?

Comment: This would be a great question for the Code Review community :)

Comment: Read the FAQ on [codereview.se] and see if your question fits there. Asking for "good practice" on Stack Overflow is not exactly on topic.

Comment: Your solution is totally fine in my book..

Comment: Thank You guys !!

Sorry for the question at the wrong place. I didn't know the Code Review.

I posted there. Please, anyone can close the question?

Comment: You can delete the question yourself. I would use two columns or the Range datatype in Postgresql for this as it will be very difficult to query this column.